# how to display mysql query output in HTML Horizontal table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is my Query....

```
$sql20 = "SELECT size, SUM(sizeorderqty) as oqty FROM `colsize_tbl` WHERE Style_no='4320'";
```

These are the PHP code that written to display the output in a html table

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'> ";
while ($row20=mysql_fetch_array($result20)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Size </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row20['size']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Order Qty </td>";
echo "<td>" . $row20['oqty']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

but my Output is

```
Size      | L   |
Order Qty | 300 |
Size      |M    |
Order Qty |250  |
Size      |S    |
Order Qty |500  |
```

Please advice me to show above table in following format

```
Size       | S   | M   | L   |
Order Qty  | 500 | 250 | 300 |
```

Comment: I edited my answer to what I think you're looking for. Please let me know if this works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your HTML markup is a little invalid.

Since I can't run the code locally without your database, could you let me know if this works?

This is your query:

```
$sql20 = "SELECT size, SUM(sizeorderqty) as oqty FROM `colsize_tbl` WHERE Style_no='4320'";
```

This is the PHP code that displays the output in a HTML table:

```
<?php
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'>";
    $sizes = array();
    $oqtys = array();
    while ($row20 = mysql_fetch_array($result20)) {
        $sizes[] = $row20['size'];
        $oqtys[] = $row20['oqty'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Size</td>";
    foreach($sizes as $size) {
        echo "<td>" . $size . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td>Order Qty</td>";
    foreach($oqtys as $oqty) {
        echo "<td>" . $oqty . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to what I think you're looking for. Please let me know if this works or not.

Comment: S | 300 | 200 | 500 | 200 |500 ............if the same size repeating again and again how to display only Order Quantity in front of size  Horizontally like this comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'> ";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Size </td>"
while ($row20=mysql_fetch_array($result20)){
echo "<td>" . $row20['size']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> Order Qty </td>"
while ($row20=mysql_fetch_array($result20)){
echo "<td>" . $row20['size']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>"
echo "</table>";
?>
```

================================================================================
OUTPUT will be like that

Size       | S   | M   | L   |

Order Qty  | 500 | 250 | 300 |